# image-rendering: crisp-edges and smooth values report invalid property value in Chrome

Tags: css, image

Why would I see this? `crisp-edges` and `smooth` should be valid values for the `image-rendering` property, according to every resource...

I have used both:

```
img {
    image-rendering: smooth;
}

img {
   image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

and I get:

[image]

Using Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131. Works normally in Firefox.

Yes, both hyphens (in name and value) are present in the correct place.

This appears to be a bug in Chrome, but I wanted to make sure it wasn't me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this writing, Chrome (92.0.4515.159) does not support `image-rendering: crisp-edges;` but it does support `image-rendering: pixelated;`.

Firefox (91.0.2), on the other hand, supports `image-rendering: crisp-edges;` but not `image-rendering: pixelated;`.

These new values for `image-rendering` are still a [candidate recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-3/#the-image-rendering) which may explain why browser support for them is inconsistent. Hopefully once it's an actual recommendation browser vendors will rush to implement full support for it.

For more on what the different image rendering modes are supposed to do according to the spec and how that differs from what browsers actually implement today, see the [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).

Also possibly of interest to you is the [Chromium issue tracking support for crisp edge rendering](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=317991).

Answer (score 2):

Use `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;`

Here is the example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#examples
[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33812351)

Comment: You're right. Edited :)

Answer (score -3):

This is because the property is written as 'image rendering' and not **image-rendering** and it's **crisp-edges**

**Here a table of compatibility of the property for the crips-edges value :**
https://caniuse.com/?search=image-rendering

You can see that is a property supported by chrome since version 41.

Comment: Both hyphens are present (in both name and value). Otherwise the tooltip would say `Unknown property name`. And like I mentioned, it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Can you upload the part of your css and html which poses a problem please ?

Comment: Added CSS. HTML shouldn't matter because it applies to all images.

Comment: How, i think in chrome it's :  rendering-image: -webkit-optimize-contrast; for crisp-edges, and rendering-image: optimizeQuality; for smooth.